# Download a folder from website to client machine in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, directory

I have a folder called "Users" on server.

There are many users using this website.

For each user I create a different folder. The folder's name will be the user's name.

In that I have some default text files and a folder called "Uploaded"

File Uploaded by any user will be stored in "Uploaded" folder.

So for any specific user his files will be in "Users/Username/Uploaded".

Now I want to backup this huge data on my computer from the server. So I want to download folder called "Users".

My site is hosted on some.com.
They doesn't give facility to download that data on my computer.

So I decided to create a download page for me.

Now the question is how to download this folder named "Users"? or how can I convert this folder to a zip?

Comment: If you know the path of the folder in the server then you could probably zip the folder using System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage or 3rd party zip library. Then, write that file to the response stream.

Comment: I cant find packaging under system.io. Can you please help me for that?

Comment: You have to add that assembly into your references. Here's an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

Comment: I tried to add reference but there also I cant find system.IO.Packaging

Comment: Sorry, for that I found it in WindowsBase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I downloaded a zip file from [this link](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx)
Unzipped It and Added a reference to dll in third folder.

The Using section :

```
Using System.IO;
Using ICSharp.SharpZipLib.Zip;
```

Code :

```
ZipOutputStream zos;
String strBaseDir;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StartZip(Server.MapPath("directory name"), "filename");
    }


    protected void StartZip(string strPath, string strFileName)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = null;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        strFileName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strFileName).Replace('+', ' ');
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName + ".zip");
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(ms);
        strBaseDir = strPath + "\\";
        addZipEntry(strBaseDir);
        zos.Finish();
        zos.Close();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        Response.End();
    }


    protected void addZipEntry(string PathStr)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(PathStr);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo item in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            addZipEntry(item.FullName);
        }
        foreach (FileInfo item in di.GetFiles())
        {
            FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(item.FullName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string strEntryName = item.FullName.Replace(strBaseDir, "");
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(strEntryName);
            zos.PutNextEntry(entry);
            zos.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

I got this code from [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1193746.aspx)

I converted it to vb.net. Below is the code for VB.NET Users :

Imports section :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports ICSharp.SharpZipLib.Zip
```

Code :

```
Dim zos as ZipOutputStream
Dim strBaseDir as String

Public Sub btnBackUpDatabase_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBackUpDatabase.Click

        StartZip(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "Database")

    End Sub

    Protected Sub StartZip(ByVal strPath As String, ByVal strFileName As String)
        Dim ms As IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        strFileName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strFileName).Replace("+"c, " "c)
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFileName & ".zip")
        ms = New IO.MemoryStream()
        zos = New ZipOutputStream(ms)
        strBaseDir = strPath & "\"
        addZipEntry(strBaseDir)
        zos.Finish()
        zos.Close()
        Response.Clear()
        Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray())
        Response.[End]()

    End Sub


    Protected Sub addZipEntry(ByVal PathStr As String)
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(PathStr)
        For Each item As IO.DirectoryInfo In di.GetDirectories()
            addZipEntry(item.FullName)
        Next
        For Each item As IO.FileInfo In di.GetFiles()
            Dim fs As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenRead(item.FullName)
            Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            Dim strEntryName As String = item.FullName.Replace(strBaseDir, "")
            Dim entry As New ZipEntry(strEntryName)
            zos.PutNextEntry(entry)
            zos.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            fs.Close()
        Next
    End Sub
```